How to set mapping in AstroNvim?
I set following in lua/community.lua:
---@type LazySpec
return {
  "AstroNvim/astrocommunity",
  { import = "astrocommunity.pack.lua" },
  { import = "astrocommunity.pack.java" },
}

And I set the following in lua/plugins/astrolsp.lua :
    mappings = {
      n = {
        gl = { function() vim.diagnostic.open_float() end, desc = "Hover diagnostics" },
        gh = { function() vim.lsp.buf.hover() end, desc = "Show LSP Hover" },
      },
    },

    on_attach = function(client, bufnr)

    end,

But, when I try to use gh for the hover effect in a Java project, nothing happens.
